# How to dynamically set ProjectVersion with Sonar-Runner.bat

Tags: powershell, parameters, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Is there a way to use sonar-runner to dynamically update the project version for every build without having to manually update the sonar-project.properties file each time? 
(note: this is for a non-mavenized .NET MVC app)

Was trying to parameterize the properties file having it reference an environment var set automatically

Added in sonar-runner.bat

> > for /f "delims=" %%i in ('hg identify -n') do set HG_LOCAL_REV=%%i

Modified sonar-project.properites

> > sonar.projectVersion=%HG_LOCAL_REV%  #don't want to have to manually update this

Would be great if we could just pass the projectVersion as a parameter for sonar-runner.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create a simple template file as a quick work around. 
Just search/replace for a unique string in the template file and save to a new sonar-project.properties file for the project.

Here's some sample code in case anyone's interested:

```
$hg_version = hg identify -n
(get-content {C:\dev\myProj\sonar-project.template | foreach-object {$_ -replace "my_proj_version", $hg_version}) | set-content c:\dev\myProj\sonar-project.properties
sonar-runner
```

Hope this is helpful for anyone else finding this.

Answer (score 6):

You can remove "sonar.projectVersion" altogether from sonar-project.properties, and pass the value as a command line argument instead, when launching the sonar-runner:

`sonar-runner -Dsonar.projectVersion="something"`

Comment: Hi Dinish, I've actually tried that before but sonar-runner does not seem to recognize that particular option unfortunately. Throws the following error: ERROR: Unrecognized option: .projectVersion=1234.   Perhaps I might be missing something?  Also thinking a possible option may be to generate a new properties file off a template every time i kick off sonar-runner....

Comment: Notice the D in front of the property name, this is not a typo. So you really want "-Dsonar.projectVersion", not just "-sonar.projectVersion".

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dinesh.  I did not forget the -D switch. Ex) sonar-runner -Dsonar.projectVersion=1234

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Sonar-runner (mentioned in the original post) is deprecated and replaced with [SonarQube Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner).

This is a working recipe for an iOS (Swift) project with TeamCity (version 2017.1.4) and SonarQube scanner (version 2.9.0.670). I'm adding it here as a future reference to myself and in case someone else needs it:

**sonar-project.properties**

- Add line:
  `sonar.projectVersion=${env.APP_VERSION}-SNAPSHOT`

**TeamCity Build Config, "Parameters"**

- Define an environment variable called: `APP_VERSION` + add other parameters such as `sonar.host.url` to avoid coupling source code with the instance version, passwords, etc.

**TeamCity Build Config, Build step 1 (Command line)**

- Add script (be sure to replace `$MY_APP_FOLDER$` with the real name of the folder:

  `echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.APP_VERSION' value='$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleShortVersionString" "$MY_APP_FOLDER$/Info.plist")']"`

**TeamCity Build Config, Build step 2 (Command line)**

- Add script (assuming develop is the branch that is reported to SonarQube):

  `if [ %teamcity.build.branch% = "develop" ]
  then
  SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS=-Xmx1024m sonar-scanner -e \
  -Dsonar.host.url=%system.sonar.host.url%\
  -Dsonar.login=%system.sonar.login%\
  -Dsonar.password=%system.sonar.password%\
  -Dsonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output.bypass=true
  fi`